# How can I show this XML table in PHP

Tags: php, xml, html-table

I have this XML with a table on it, and I have no idea how to show the table in PHP, html does not recognize the nodes as a table.

Do I have to read each individual node and change it to < tr> < td>? Or there's a more automated way to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<afpdb lang="fr-FR">
    <head>
        <message type="203" file="s4133-0000000-203-fr" timestamp="2014-04-16T12:16:26+02:00" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <competition id="866" label="Brésil 2014">
            <discipline code="FB" name="Football">
                <evt id="4133" label="Brésil 2014" gender="M" date="2014-06-12T00:00:00-03:00">
                    <country iso="BRA" code="BRA" name="Brésil" />
                    <phase id="2714" code="TP8FI" type="PH1PT">
                        <group id="9276" name="C" label="Groupe C">
                            <table type="TAFUL">
                                <thead>
                                    <tcol num="1" type="TCVAL" code="CCPOS" />
                                    <tcol num="2" type="TCXML" code="CCEQU" />
                                    <tcol num="3" type="TCVAL" code="CCPTS" />
                                    <tcol num="4" type="TCVAL" code="CCJOU" />
                                    <tcol num="5" type="TCVAL" code="CCGAG" />
                                    <tcol num="6" type="TCVAL" code="CCNUL" />
                                    <tcol num="7" type="TCVAL" code="CCPER" />
                                    <tcol num="8" type="TCVAL" code="CC_BP" />
                                    <tcol num="9" type="TCVAL" code="CC_BC" />
                                    <tcol num="10" type="TCVAL" code="CCDIF" />
                                </thead>
                                <trow>
                                    <tcol num="1" val="1" />
                                    <tcol num="2">
                                        <team id="2090" type="CENAT" display="Brésil">
                                            <country iso="BRA" code="BRA" name="Brésil" />
                                        </team>
                                    </tcol>
                                    <tcol num="3" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="4" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="5" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="6" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="7" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="8" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="9" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="10" val="0" />
                                </trow>
                                <trow>
                                    <tcol num="1" val="1" />
                                    <tcol num="2">
                                        <team id="2103" type="CENAT" display="Cameroun">
                                            <country iso="CMR" code="CMR" name="Cameroun" />
                                        </team>
                                    </tcol>
                                    <tcol num="3" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="4" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="5" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="6" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="7" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="8" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="9" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="10" val="0" />
                                </trow>
                                <trow>
                                    <tcol num="1" val="1" />
                                    <tcol num="2">
                                        <team id="2107" type="CENAT" display="Croatie">
                                            <country iso="HRV" code="CRO" name="Croatie" />
                                        </team>
                                    </tcol>
                                    <tcol num="3" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="4" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="5" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="6" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="7" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="8" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="9" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="10" val="0" />
                                </trow>
                                <trow>
                                    <tcol num="1" val="1" />
                                    <tcol num="2">
                                        <team id="2175" type="CENAT" display="Mexique">
                                            <country iso="MEX" code="MEX" name="Mexique" />
                                        </team>
                                    </tcol>
                                    <tcol num="3" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="4" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="5" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="6" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="7" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="8" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="9" val="0" />
                                    <tcol num="10" val="0" />
                                </trow>
                            </table>
                        </group>
                    </phase>
                </evt>
            </discipline>
        </competition>
    </body>
</afpdb>
```

Comment: You are going to need an XML DOM Parser. Or you could write an XSLT. There is no "automated" or let's say automagical way.

Comment: Open this file in any text editor that supports "find&replace" feature (CTRL+H ) .It would be a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple tutorial showing you how to parse an xml file in php using PHP5's simpleXML functions:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5
In this case the code could be this:

```
<?php
$data = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$source = $data->body->competition->discipline->evt->phase->group;
foreach ($source->table as $tableElement) {
echo "<h4>THEAD</h4>";
foreach ($tableElement->thead[0] as $tcol) {
    echo "Num attribute: ".$tcol->attributes()->num."<br />";
    echo "Type attribute: ".$tcol->attributes()->type."<br />";
    echo "Code attribute: ".$tcol->attributes()->code."<br />";
    echo "####<br/>";
}
for ($i=0;$i<count($tableElement->trow);$i++){
    echo "<h4>TROW ".$i."</h4>";
    foreach ($tableElement->trow[$i] as $tcol) {
        echo "Num attribute: ".$tcol->attributes()->num."<br />";
        echo "Val attribute: ".$tcol->attributes()->val."<br />";

        echo "####<br/>";
    }
}


}
?>
```

then you can modify the code to be shown in a simple html table..

Comment: You need to create a file called file.xml that contains the xml content you provided in your question, in the same folder you have the php script.

Comment: yes i did that this is my XML, and it is in the same folder as php script, also named file.xml (for testing purposes)
http://pastebin.com/mc6CA69y

Comment: i need to show all the contents of that XML in Html, do you think it will be achievable your way or need another aproach?

Comment: @RonEskinder this time you provided a file a little bit different structured.. this approach works only if xml files has the same structure, otherwise you'll need to modify your script in order to parse different xml file structure... or you can use xls stylesheet, it's a kind of css for xml files :) take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Answer (score -1):

ended up taken @Cristian 's advise make an XLS template for the XML and then process in php, here is the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>

  <!-- Groups --> 
  <xsl:for-each select="afpdb/body/competition/discipline/evt/phase/group">
  <xsl:sort select="match/@id"/>

  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">
        <div class="widget-block">
          <div class="widget-head">
            <h5><i class="color-icons soccer_co"></i>  <xsl:value-of select="@label"/></h5>
            </div>
                <div class="widget-content">
                <div class="widget-box">
                <table class="table user-tbl">
                        <xsl:for-each select="match">
                        <xsl:variable name="flag1" select="res[1]/team/country/@iso" />
                        <xsl:variable name="flag2" select="res[2]/team/country/@iso" />
                        <xsl:variable name="dt" select="@timestamp"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="link_id" select="@id"/>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="center"><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($dt, 9, 2), '/', substring($dt, 6, 2), '/', substring($dt, 1, 4), ' - ', substring($dt, 12, 5))" /><br/><strong><xsl:value-of select="@dow"/></strong></td>
                            <td class="center"><img width="35px" src="{concat('http://vivo.futebolivr.com/LIB/comentarios/flags/',$flag1,'.png')}"  /><br/><h4><xsl:value-of select="res[1]/team/@display"/></h4></td>
                            <td class="center"><xsl:value-of select="datas/stadium/@name"/><span class="user-position"><xsl:value-of select="datas/stadium/city/@name"/></span></td>
                            <td class="center"><img width="35px" src="{concat('http://vivo.futebolivr.com/LIB/comentarios/flags/',$flag2,'.png')}"  /><h4><xsl:value-of select="res[2]/team/@display"/></h4></td>
                            <td class="center"><a class="iframe btn btn-info cboxElement" href="http://vivo.futebolivr.com/LIB/comentarios/comment_live2.php?id={$link_id}">Comentarios</a></td>
                          </tr>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </xsl:for-each>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image: Final result]